# Is the free group on two generators generated by two elements as a monoid?

Tags: free-groups, monoid

I was musing about this today and couldn't come up with an answer. Obviously it can be generated as a monoid by the four elements $a$, $b$, $a^{-1}$, and $b^{-1}$.  After some playing around I was able to come up with three elements that generate it as a monoid: $ab$, $ab^{-1}$, and $a^{-1}$.

But I haven't been able to come up with two generators, nor an argument as to why that should be impossible.

Comment: Nice fake. You had me going there.

Comment: You might ask  the same question about the free group on one generator.

Comment: How do you get $a$ from your three generators?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin $a = ab \cdot a^{-1} \cdot ab^{-1}$. A nicer triple would be $ab, a^{-1}, b^{-1}$.

Comment: @Somos The free group on one generator is a bit easier to figure out :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The free group on two generators maps onto $\Bbb Z^2$. (This is its Abelianisation). If it were generated by two elements as a monoid, then so
would $\Bbb Z^2$. But that's not so. 
If you have two elements $a$, $b$ of $\Bbb Z^2$
generating it as a monoid, they certainly generate it as an Abelian group,
so they must be linearly independent as vectors. But in that case
$-a-b$ is not in the submonoid of $\Bbb Z^2$ generated by $a$ and $b$.

Likewise, a free group on $n$ generators cannot be generated as a monoid
by $n$ elements.

Comment: Nice proof and generalization! I had briefly considered the abelianization, but not carefully enough to see this reasoning.

Answer (score 6):

And, further generalizing the rank 2 case, the $(n+1)$-tuple $(a_1^{-1}, a_2^{-1},\ldots,a_n^{-1},a_1a_2\cdots a_n)$ generates all of the rank $n$ free group as a monoid.

Comment: This does not seem to be an $(n + 1)$-tuple, but rather a $(2n)$-tuple.

Comment: @Yanior Weg: the $(n+1)$-st element of the tuple is the product $a_1\cdots a_n$.